# Is there a column break in my paragraph? How many lines in is it?

Tags: javascript, css

CSS has a concept of widows and orphans, so the browser has a way of knowing how many lines cross the column (or, if printing, page) boundary.

Is there a way to know this in JavaScript?

It could be done in a very unpleasant & brittle way using the geometry of the elements, but this seems like a pretty undesirable outcome.

For example: https://codepen.io/notionparallax/pen/BvLZeB

```
document.querySelectorAll("p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5").forEach(
    (x) => {

      let boxW    = Math.round(x.getBoundingClientRect().width);
      let clientW = Math.round(x.clientWidth);
      if (boxW !== clientW) {
        console.log(x);
        x.classList.add("has-break");
      }

      try {
        if (x.nextElementSibling.offsetLeft !== x.offsetLeft) {
          console.log(x);
          x.classList.add("end-of-column");
        }
      } catch(error) {}

    }
)
```

In a library like [Paged.js](https://www.pagedmedia.org/paged-js/) they have a concept of a *break token* that indicates where in the element the break occurs (if indeed there is a break). I'd imagine that this is the kind of thing that might be made possible by [Houdini](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/05/houdini) eventually. I'm interested to see if there's way of interrogating an element to see if it wraps to the next page/column, using conventional methods.

### Use case

I want to know where the element breaks so that I can see if I ought to walk back up the DOM an put a break in ahead of the preceding header. This is partially handled by widows and orphans for the element itself, but I'd like to be able to have a finer grain of control so that—for instance—a chapter doesn't start right at the bottom of a page. I'd be fine with two lines of a paragraph between two paragraphs, but a paragraph that follows a heading should get a bit more breathing room.

### Update

I'm not interested in solutions to the use case, I'm interested in answers to the question in the title. The use case illustrates *one* possible application of the information that I'm interested in, not the sole reason for the question.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to add a page break for printing?

Comment: HTML pages grow to fit their content. What is a "page boundary" in this context?

Comment: @diodeus if using columns inside a block element then the column break will happen there. If printing, the column will break at the page boundary.

Comment: @ItayGal I'm trying to control page breaks, I don't actually _need_ the answer any more, but I'm interested to see if there _is_ an answer.

Comment: @Ben after reading your question again and looking at your example, it seems you're trying to identify something regarding the width of the page rather than the page break (height) at a certain point when printing it. Can you try to explain better what is that you're looking for? Your original question was "I'm trying to make headings stay with their following paragraph. InDesign and Word both have this idea, but CSS doesn't seem to." but now I think you might aiming for something else.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly you are looking for and what are the undesirable outcomes?

Comment: @MunimMunna I added a little clarification. If the query works robustly, then there are no undesirable outcomes, but I can see lots of edge cases that would break the example code I gave. It also doesn't say _where_ element the break is, just that there is one.

Comment: @ItayGal I added an explanation. I think I could solve that specific use case with an Adjacent sibling combinator, but I'm in it for the abstract question now, can the element be queried, or is that just magic for now?

Comment: I didn't understand why widows and orphans are related and why are you talking about columns. Printing page breaks only refer to the height. I think you're confusing 2 different things here.

Answer (score 10):

You can add `page-break-before: always;` to a tag, this will set a page break before the tag. For example, adding this CSS to h1 will create a new page before each h1 title

```css
h1 {
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Page 1</h1>
  <p>content here</p>
  <h1>Page 2</h1>
  <p>content here</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

It sounds like you want to find a way to identify, not set a printing page break, but note that the page size can vary, the scale and also the printing margins can be changed which obviously affect the page's content and the page break location. You don't have a way to find the page break in a generic way.

**UPDATE 2**

Each browser implements its own logic of how to divide the pages. For example, I tried to print this page from Chrome, Firefox and IE. There is a few line difference between them, and I didn't set anything, just used the default settings

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

IE:

[image: IE]

Comment: You have completely **wrong answer** because OP wrote _Is there a way to know this in JavaScript?_ He wants to do it automatically using JavaScript and not manually. This is not even an alternative! And he is asking about column break and not the page break! Additionally you write: _You don't have a way to find the page break in a generic way._ This is also wrong – because for example **[Google Docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs)** does it automatically on client side.

Comment: @Bharata Maybe you should check the question history and see the comments before. He initially asked about page breaks, then changed his question, but still gives examples with page break. As I commented on the post he seems to confuse 2 different things together, page breaks and column breaks, and he still didn't clarify his question...

Comment: I have seen **[the history of his question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53823303/revisions)** before I have commented. From **[his first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53823303/1)** he was always constant about his wish to do it using JavaScript – automatically detecting of column break. He does also not confuse 2 different things together. For your question he answered you: _I'm trying to control page breaks_ because your question was about page breaks. Yes, they are a litle bit similar in this case, but his wish is to control it automatically using JavaScript.

Comment: Well, if he wants to "control page breaks" as you're saying , then adding a `page-break-before` style as I suggested is the answer. If he wants to identify "column break" that's a completely different thing, isn't it?  Also from the OP question: "interrogating an element to see if it wraps to the next page/column"

Comment: I'm sorry, do you have a solution? Can you know before a user decide to print the page, what margins or what page size will he use? In my answer you can see I'm referring to this unknown parameters and this is the reason I'm saying there is no way to write it generally. Each browser implements its own logical of page content per page, after these parameters were selected (and some pages will be printed differently from a different browser). If you can think of a way to get this info without forcing the page-break, answer the question and get the bounty :)

Comment: Maybe there is no way to write it for someone, but not generally like you wrote, because Google Docs does it automatically on client side using JavaScript. This JS is very obfuscated. And about browsers: your print screenshots from different browsers have nothing to do with JS calculation. Browsers do this calculation not using JS! I would like to recommend you to use Google Docs to see how it works there.

Comment: Are you printing with JS? It's all about the page content when printing it, this is why there is no way of knowing. My screenshot tells everything, it shows why no matter what your calculation with JS will be, it cannot be correct for all the apps that will print it...

Answer (score 4):

**Simple solution**

First, lets fix orphans rule for paragraphs, for example:

```css
p {
  orphans: 2;
}
```

Then, orphans rule for headers:

```css
h1 + p {
  orphans: 4;
}

.new-chapter {
  break-before: column;
}
```

Finally we need js to add class `new-chapter` to h1 to prevent headers being apart from paragraph:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("h1 + p").forEach(p => {
  const h1 = p.previousElementSibling
  if (h1.offsetLeft !== p.offsetLeft) {
    h1.classList.add(`new-chapter`)
    h1.style.opacity = 0.99
  }
  // after inserting css class need to refresh dom
  setTimeout(() => {
    h1.style.opacity = 1
  }, 2000)
})
```

Check [DEMO](https://codepen.io/sultan99/pen/GPVBxp)

Answer (score 4):

Adding this answer only for future readers in the event that the API mentioned below becomes a standard implementation in major browsers and simplifies the js required to identify column breaks within elements. The below is not currently useful in production code as no major browser I am aware of fully implements the API below at the time of this answer.

There is a [CSS Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) API called [GeometryUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeometryUtils) with a `getBoxQuads()` method that returns objects representing each CSS fragment of a node. The only browser I am aware of where it is mostly implemented at the time of this answer is [Firefox Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/nightly/all/).

The method makes it fairly simple to identify breaks within an element because it returns a [DOMQuad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMQuad) object for each CSS fragment of a node, so you could do something like...

```
const frags = document.querySelector('p').getBoxQuads().length;
```

...where `frags` represents the number of CSS fragments for the selected element. If the element has more than 1 fragment, then there is a break. You would still need additional js to determine the number of lines, etc but this would enable you to isolate those efforts to just elements with a break. If you are interested in experimenting with `getBoxQuads()` as shown above, you will need to download Firefox Nightly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love [benvc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9958942/benvc)'s approach to work, but it seems like that idea was dropped by the world.

This is a clumsy method that can tell *if* a `p` breaks, and then uses an even more clumsy method to identify the last word in the first column.

I'd be interested to see if there's a more elegant solution.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".poem_container p").forEach((p) => {
  const rectWidth = p.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const reportedWidth = p.offsetWidth;
  if (reportedWidth > rectWidth * 0.9 && reportedWidth < rectWidth * 1.1) {
    p.classList.add("single-col");
  } else {
    p.classList.add("multi-col");
    let words = p.innerHTML
      .split(" ")
      .map((word) => `<span class="w">${word}</span>`)
      .join(" ");
    p.innerHTML = words;
    const leftEdge = p.getBoundingClientRect().x;
    let lastOne;
    p.querySelectorAll("span.w").forEach((w) => {
      const r = w.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (r.x + r.width < leftEdge + reportedWidth) {
        w.classList.add("in-col-1");
        if (w.innerHTML.trim() != ""){
            lastOne = w;
        }
      }
    });
    lastOne.classList.add("last-word");
    console.log(lastOne);
  }
});
```

```css
.poem_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  column-count: 3;
  outline: 1px solid purple;
}

.single-col {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.multi-col {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.in-col-1 {
  background: orange;
}

.last-word {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="poem_container">
  <p>This is a paragraph, it's a short one.</p>
  <p>
    The following is the first paragraph from Pale Fire, it's a 999 line poem. It's not particularly pertinent to this but it was easily to hand.
  </p>
  <p>
    I was the shadow of the waxwing slain / By the false azure in the windowpane; / I was the smudge of ashen fluff&mdash;and I / Lived on, flew on, in the reflected sky. / And from the inside, too, I'd duplicate / Myself, my lamp, an apple on a plate: /
    Uncurtaining the night, I'd let dark glass / Hang all the furniture above the grass, / And how delightful when a fall of snow / Covered my glimpse of lawn and reached up so / As to make chair and bed exactly stand / Upon that snow, out in that crystal
    land!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: well, it worked in the preview...